# Bitbucket showing conflicts in file changes but not at top

Tags: merge, bitbucket, conflict, git-merge-conflict

I'm trying to merge a new branch I have created into develop. There were merge conflicts on the branch which I resolved locally and then pushed the changes to Bitbucket.

Now, you can see here that there are no conflicts flagged and I can happily merge this into our develop branch without any problems.

[image]

However, threaded throughout the changes I have things like:

[image]

Why are these old conflicts showing? I really don't want to merge and to have these appearing in every PR I raise... but it makes no sense to me that having clearly resolved these conflicts, they are still showing.

Comment: I'm having the same situation.  Did you ever find anything about this? @DevB1

Comment: Sadly not. It was a real odd one. In the end I literally created a new branch and copied the files over - which was hideous. But this was very strange, particularly as since then I have continued to rebase in exactly the same way and never seen this issue again!